# Android: Default actions of Back Button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-task

I know that when we press back button, the default function `onBackPressed()` is called.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

This doc say that "The default implementation simply finishes the current activity".
What does it means, does it mean the default onBackPressed() include the function `finish()`?

What is the implementation inside finish()?
Is that `onDestroy()`?

Comment: The Android developer documentation explains the Android lifecycle model. It shows you what finish() does and when onDestroy() is called.  You read that documentation, and you'll learn what exactly the back button does.
Often, you don't want the default behavior of the back button. When you create an app, you should determine what the most logical behavior of the back button is, the behavior that the user would expect.

Answer (score 5):

This is how implementation looks like:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

---

Of course on Android 2.3 and lower it's like this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
     finish();
}
```

There was no Fragments API.

---

You can always check sources yourself in your IDE or on the [web](http://grepcode.com/)

Comment: I wanna ask a question, what's inside **finish()**?

Comment: in finish() it close the current activity means it destroy current activity  and it shows previously pausedActivity or previousely opened Activity which is in queue

Comment: The answer below said that "Activity is not destroyed completely when back button is pressed", is that true?

Comment: When finish() is called system go through lifecycle methods and eventually call onDestroy() for your Activity. Previously visible Activity is shown, it does not have to be your app. @shylendra is wrong saying "Activity is not destroyed completely when back button is pressed"

Comment: Regarding "what's inside fnish()", as I wrote in my answer check the source or the web e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.finish%28%29 You have to learn making use of the source, it's a very good practice to improve Android programming.

Comment: You are welcome. If it is enough for you then please chose your correct answer.